# isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-x)$ and $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> I want to prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-x)\cong \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$.

Using fundamental theorem of isomorphism I have to find a surjective homomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, but I don't know how to define this.

Comment: 2. I make an exception and give you a hint: the required homomorphism sends $a_0+a_1X+\cdots+a_nX^n$ to $(a_0,a_0)+(a_1,a_1)(1,0)+\cdots+(a_n,a_n)(1,0)$. (I've wrote it like this to make clear how to find it: the constants $a$ are sent to $(a,a)$ and $X$ is sent to $(1,0)$.)

Comment: 3. For the three answerers: it seems the OP wants to use the fundamental theorem of isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** You want $x^2 \equiv x$ in the factor, this implies that $x^k \equiv x$ in the factor for all $k \geq 1$.

Therefore, in the factor, you will have

$$a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n \equiv a_0+(a_1+....+a_n)x$$

It should be obvious how you can chose a pair of numbers from the last expression.

**Alternate Hint** $x^2-x=x(x-1)$ is the intersection of the kernels of $P(x) \to P(0)$ and $P(x) \to P(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

There are two special elements of $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$. They are $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$. These two elements have the property that $e_1^2=e_1$ and $e_2^2=e_2$ and $e_1e_2=0$ and $e_1+e_2=1$. We call them orthogonal idempotents. Can you find two such elements in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x(1-x))$?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Over_univariate_polynomial_rings_and_Euclidean_domains), you can do this quite quickly.  Since $1 = x - (x-1) \in (x) + (x-1)$, then the ideals $(x-1)$ and $(x)$ are comaximal.  Then the Chinese Remainder Theorem implies that
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x(x-1))} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x)} \times \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x-1)} \, .
$$
Can you simplify these last two quotients?